# Accessing categories of a relationship field in EE2.6

Tags: channel-entries, categories, relationships

I have a channel with a single relationship field. In my template, I want to access the relationship's list of categories. Unfortunately, this does not work: (example simplified to illustrate my point)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="parent"}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <p>{relationship_field:categories backspace="2"}{category_name}, {/relationship_field:categories}</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any ideas on how to make something like this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to have your categories tags set within the relationship tag pair like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="parent"}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {relationship_field}
        <p>{relationship_field:categories backspace="2"}{category_name}, {/relationship_field:categories}</p>
    {/relationship_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```